# How to prevent Meteor's accounts-base from auto-publishing the email of the current user?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-publications

According to [Meteor's documentation](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-users) on the Accounts package:

> By default, the current user’s username, emails and profile are published to the client.

Is it possible to prevent Meteor from auto-publishing these fields? I know it's just for the user that is logged in, but that user could take a walk or be online somewhere public.

This structure of the code seems to be defined in [accounts_server.js](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/f04160aea83f272cd5bfe8b7c3782e8c2b28255b/packages/accounts-base/accounts_server.js) (search for autopublish and email - lines 37 and 696).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward way to do this is going to be to modify the value of `Accounts._defaultPublishFields.projection` and remove the emails key. An easy way to do this while keeping the other values is to use a combination of rest and spread like so:

```js
import { Accounts } from 'meteor/accounts-base';

const { emails, ...fields } = Accounts._defaultPublishFields.projection;
Accounts._defaultPublishFields.projection = { ...fields };
```

Just make sure this runs on the server and you should be good to go.